# Can not open mvc4 project in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

i'm newbie for mvc4 this is my first project (web app)
i get source project from my friends. they work normally. 
when i open project VS2012 and then alert

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio does not have the following
>   project types installed or does not support them. You can still open
>   these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were
>   originally created.
>      - B2B.Web, "D:\ServiceClone\ServiceClone-1706\B2B.Web\B2B.Web.csproj"

and in solution explorer i can not load a project. at the project name it says incompatible

How resolve?

PS.  I searched in google but I have not find a work solution. Sorry I'm not good at English :P

Comment: Which Visual Studio you have? Express, Professional, Premium? If Express which type: desktop, web, for windows phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to open it in visual studio 2010?
and also try to Uninstall you Visual studio 2012 completely (save your projects if you want to). Then do a clean installation of Visual studio 2012.

Comment: I already tried it in VS2010 but still the same VS2012. i'll try to uninstall VS2012, Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install MVC4 on that machine first.

To download MVC4 set up [Click here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4).